# Adding explicit return to closure causes compiler error: A compiler bug?

Tags: generics, types, swift, compiler-errors, closures

Consider this generic method (only the types are important, not what it does):

```
func flatMap<SourceType, TargetType>(source: [SourceType], transform: SourceType [TargetType]) -> [TargetType] {
    return []
}
```

Following call to the method compiles nicely:

```
let seq = flatMap(["some", "string"], { s in [1, 2] })
```

However, just adding explicit return to closure cases compile error:

```
let seq = flatMap(["some", "string"], { s in return [1, 2] }) //ERROR: Cannot convert the expression's type ... to type 'StringLiteralConvertible'
```

The compiler can still infer the types in the same way it did it in first case, right? Where is the difference (I cannot see any)? How can I make the second case compile if I need that `return` in place?

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I would also say so. I wanted to verify it because there are several things about Swift type system that I thought to be bugs but after posting to SO, it was explained to me they were meant to be so or even features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you make the return type of the closure explicit:

```
let seq = flatMap(["some", "string"], { s -> [Int] in return [1, 2] })
```

What is interesting is that it only happens if the generic value isn't defined anywhere else. So the sorted closure of an array doesn't have this issue:

```
[1,2,3].sorted{a,b in return a < b} //works
```

And if you, for some reason, add a parameter to function with the TargetType, it also works:

```
func flatMap<SourceType, TargetType>(source: [SourceType],aTarget:TargetType, transform: SourceType -> [TargetType]) -> [TargetType] {
    return []
}

let seq = flatMap(["some", "string"], 1, {s in return [1, 2]}) //works
```

It's either a compiler bug or a way to force things to be more explicit in potentially ambiguous situations.