# Closure expression {exp} vs {return exp}

Tags: ios, macos, swift, closures

Given the following function declaration

```
func foo(f:()->Foo) -> Bar
```

What is the difference in the following two variants of code using Closure Expressions:

**A)**

```
let result = foo { 
    return Foo()
}
```

**B)**

```
let result = foo { 
    Foo()
}
```

Please notice that the type of the constant `result` is not specified and must be inferred.

The reason why I am asking is that the compiler seems to make a difference - at least currently. This is due to the fact that in quite many scenarios the compiler is unable to infer the type of the closure expression when using `return Foo()` as the closure expression. Omitting the `return` on the other hand may issue another error by the compiler since it may require that `return` (even though I disagree with the compiler, but I do digress ...)

The issue can most often be solved by completely specifying the closure expression, e.g.:

```
let result = foo { () -> Foo in
    return Foo()
}
```

or sometimes it can be alleviated by *explicitly* specifying the type of `result`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26305402/335858

Comment: dasblinkenlight: "This looks like a compiler bug to me." I agree, this might be an obvious reason. I already filed a related bug report a couple of days (weeks?) ago.

Answer (score 0):

`foo` function returns `Bar`. So compiler can easily infer that `result` is `Bar`. `Foo()` returns `Foo` instance. So compiler can easily infer that closure is correct whether you specify `return` or not. Here is the code that I play with in Xcode 6.0.1 playground.

```
struct Foo {
    func foos() {
        println("foos")
    }
}

struct Bar {
    func bars() {
        println("bars")
    }
}

func foo(f: () -> Foo) -> Bar {
    let foof = f()
    foof.foos()
    return Bar()
}

let result = foo {
    return Foo()
}

result.bars()
```